# Rate and review system for wordpress website

Tags: php, css, wordpress, review, bubble.io

I have a professor Rate and review website for Lebanese universities. I have created a new rating system with animation on bubble.io ( https://professor-advisor.bubbleapps.io/version-test?debug_mode=true )

but I want to implement it on Wordpress. Is it possible to have such custom fields? and also is it possible to have the same animations? (hover and click colors and texts)

Comment: Well it depends, if you want to entirely integrate your bubble part with your WP part on the same domain, you would have to pay the Personal plan I thikn ($25 / month). Are you willing to pay that? The free plan does not seem to allow that (custom domain, etc.) https://bubble.io/pricing/compare

Comment: other than that ($) yes it is entirely possible to combine both, I can explain the general idea.

Comment: i allready have a wordpress website that is running. I made this on bubble just as a template of how i wish my wordpress system would function. I want the same system to be implemented on wordpress.

Comment: Note how the values will be re-used in the main section of the professor's info. eg, the score chart displays the average score of the submitted reviews, will the data bases be linked together if i use bubble and wordpress at the same time?

Comment: Well, quickly looking at your Bubble page source code, you will have quite a hard time fetching data and using it in your Wordpress site, in my opinion. Bubble uses a lot of homemade scripts and not plain HTML/CSS, so it's hard to read. And it's one of their goals, too. So you can't get the site for "free". Would it be possible for you to build the site either all in bubble or all in WP? What do you think.

Comment: The other way around is possible too, like creating a similar page as Bubble directly inside your WP, but you would need some knowledge of javascript, databases and a solid HTML/CSS foundation too.

Comment: ohh okay, thanks. And yes i would definitely want my website to only run on wordpress, the bubble system is just a quick draft/template of how i wish my wordpress system would function. i did it for explanatory purposes only and i do not intend on using bubble..

Comment: I realised i won't be able to implement in on wordpress with my current skills. How much work do you suggest it would take a developer to implement? will it be risky to implement?

Comment: I think you could try to either find a plugin for WP that can help you design somthing similar to your Buble page OR if you have more time follow the suggestion of Lajos of analyzing the page and rebuilding it bit by bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can achieve it. It may be a longshot, but:

- download their CSS files
- download their JS files
- look at the page-source

Working on your Wordpress theme implement the same HTML as you had on bubble. You do not necessarily need to reuse their code in all cases. When you know how a given design element or animation can be achieved, feel free to implement yourself. When not, then look at some properties on their tags, like classes and so. Search for the identifiable properties of the element you are working on at a given point in the CSS and JS files. See what happens with them. Try removing classes and CSS rules, see what happens. This way you can gradually find out what code is responsible for what element. But it may be a long process.

Alternatively you could implement something similar on your own. I like this option better, because, even though you will face some difficulties while doing so, once you are done you will be familiar with your own code and will be able to customize it later if needed.